# Jquery horizontal scrolling, trigger/target will not scroll to proper location

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to horizontally scroll a clicked item to 0,0 of it's parent, but the parent seems to scroll to random positions.

HTML/JS

```
<div class="nav-tabs-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {

  $('.nav-tabs-wrapper a').on('click',function(){
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('.nav-tabs-wrapper').stop().animate({ scrollLeft: $($anchor).offset().left }, 300);
  });

}); 
</script>
```

SCSS

```
.nav-tabs-wrapper {
    width: 120px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;

    ul {
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        display: table;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    li {
     display: table-cell;   
    }

    a {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8d69ma7/

Ideally I would like to have these items scroll to center, but first step is just getting them to scroll properly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

here is a statical version
http://jsfiddle.net/davidsonsousa/KVs94/

And here is a dynamical solution based on the index of clicked "li"-element and its width (HTML and CSS remain the same):

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs-wrapper a').on('click',function(){
        var index = $(this).parent('li').index();
        var offset = (index) * $(this).width() - $(this).width()/2;
        $('.nav-tabs-wrapper').animate({scrollLeft: offset}, 800);
    });
});
```

Use "outerWidth(true)" instead of "width()" if you need to take padding or margin into account:

```
    var offset = (index) * $(this).outerWidth(true) - 
        ($('.nav-tabs-wrapper').width()/2 - $(this).outerWidth(true)/2);
```